# scrollTop (JS and jQuery version) won't scroll all the way to the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

I'm creating a chat app which when messages load (From Firebase), the div containing the messages scrolls to the bottom to display the most recent appended message div. scrollTop *does* somewhat work but it won't scroll all the way to the bottom, no matter what values I use for scrollTop. I've tried both the JS and the jQuery versions of scrollTop, but neither can get it to scroll to the bottom. Here's some of my code:
HTML

```
<div id="msgContainer">
   <div id="msgFeed">
      //Messages load here from a database
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#msgContainer {
  height: 165px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: visible;
}
#msgFeed {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

JS

```
function scrollToBottom (id) {
   var div = document.getElementById(id);
   div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight - div.clientHeight;
}
```

or...

```
$('#scroll').scrollTop(1000000);
```

Doesn't seem to matter which version or what values I use, it just refuses to scroll that last approximately 5% of the way to the bottom. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong??

Answer (score 3):

I dealt with a similar issue.  I was receiving a value from a web socket to put into a chat box. Whenever I used scrollTop/Height, it always scrolled to the NEXT to last message (off just a bit). Even if I put in the max or a very high value, it would not scroll all the way.

This occurs b/c the dimensions of the container (with the added item) are not yet what we expect.  A simple timeout will solve this problem:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    el.scrollTop = el.scrollHeight;
}, 500);
```

If you're using Vue.js (probably something analagous in other reactive frameworks), you can also do the following ('this' is the Vue instance):

```
this.$nextTick(
    () => (this.$refs.chat.scrollTop = this.$refs.chat.scrollHeight)
);
```

'nextTick' seems optimal, but not everyone will be using Vue. Hope this all helps someone solve this simple yet not so evident problem.

EDIT:  nextTick doesn't always seem to work.  setTimeout should always work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what element you were referring to with `#scroll` since I don't see it in your html, but try this and let me know if it still falls ~5% short.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
function scrollToBottom (id) {
    var div = document.getElementById(id);
   
    /*TRY*/
    div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight - div.clientHeight;
    /*OR*/
    $('#'+id).scrollTop(div.scrollHeight - div.clientHeight);
}
scrollToBottom('msgContainer');

});
```

```css
#msgContainer {
  height: 165px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: visible;
  border: 3px solid red
}
#msgFeed {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="msgContainer">
   <div id="msgFeed">
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      //Messages load here from a database
   </div>
</div>
```